# Prove $S^2(x) + C^2(x) = 1$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Suppose $S, C : \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ are differentiable and that (1) $S'(x) = C(x)$ and $C'(x) = −S(x)$ for all $x \in \Bbb R$, and (2) $S(0) = 0$ and $C(0) = 1$. Prove that $S^2(x) + C^2(x) = 1$ for all $x \in \Bbb R$.

I tried using the limit definition of differentiable in setting the limit as $x$ approaches $a$ of $((S(X)-S(a))/x-1)=C(x)$ and setting the limit as $x$ approaches $a$ of $((C(X)-C(a))/x-1)=-S(x)$ but I don't know if that gets me anywhere. Hints or anything would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are $S$ and $C$ just sine and cosine respectively? Or is that just coincidence? Also, here's [a reference for MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) you might find useful, which is preferred for writing up and rendering your math text on this site.

Comment: It can be shown that $S$ and $C$ *have* to be sine and cosine respectively, but I think the point of the problem is to reason about $S$ and $C$ more abstractly. Hint to the OP: Let $F = S^2 + C^2$. Take the derivative of $F$. What do you notice?

Comment: @EeveeTrainer S and C are just a coincidence, it could also be f and g, etc.

Comment: @CharlesHudgins Wow as soon as I saw the s^2 + c^2 I should have automatically thought sine and cosine, we haven't defined them in class yet so the thought didn't even occur to me.

Comment: That's a good thing. The point of this exercise is to show you that with very few assumptions that can all be formulated in the language of calculus, we can uniquely define functions which have all the familiar properties of sine and cosine without ever needing to draw a circle or a triangle.

Comment: I edited your post to get the $\LaTeX$ to work.  I hope I got all the math right!  If not, you can edit it back.  Cheers!

Answer (score 10):

Note that

$\dfrac{d}{dx}(S^2(x) + C^2(x)) = 2S(x)S'(x) + 2C(x)C'(x) = 2(S(x)S'(x) + C(x)C'(x)); \tag 1$

by hypothesis

$S'(x) = C(x) \tag 2$

and

$C'(x) = -S(x); \tag 3$

thus (1) becomes

$\dfrac{d}{dx}(S^2(x) + C^2(x)) = 2(S(x)S'(x) + C(x)C'(x)) = 2(S(x)C(x) - C(x)S(x)) = 0; \tag 4$

with

$S(0) = 0, \tag 5$

and

$C(0) = 1, \tag 6$

we have

$S^2(0) + C^2(0) = 1; \tag 7$

by (4), $S^2(x) + C^2(x)$ is constant; thus from (7),

$\forall x \in \Bbb R, \; S^2(x) + C^2(x) = 1, \tag 8$

$OE\Delta$.

***Note Added in Edit, Wedesday 4 September 2019 9:20 PM PST:***  As pointed out in the comments to the question itself, $S(x)$ and $C(x)$ are in fact $\sin x$ and $\cos x$, respectively.  This may be seen as follows:  from (2), (3) we have

$S''(x) = C'(x) = -S(x), \tag 9$

and

$C''(x) = -S'(x) = -C(x); \tag{10}$

thus $S(x)$ and $C(x)$ each obey the differential equation

$y''(x) + y(x) = 0; \tag{11}$

it is well known that the unique non-vanishing solution to this equation with

$y(0) = 0, \; y'(0) = 1 \tag{12}$

is in fact $S(x)$; likewise $C(x)$ solves (11) with

$y(0) = 1, \; y'(0) = 0, \tag{13}$

where the initial conditions on $y'(0)$ are easily had from (2)-(3), (5)-(6).  Thus we infer that

$S(x) = \sin x, \; C(x) = \cos x. \tag{14}$

***End of Note.***

Comment: "is in fact $S(x)$" <-- I think you mean "is in fact $\sin(x)$", no?

Comment: Also, "it is well known" is true, but this is a somewhat nontrivial result.

Comment: From my point of view, you deserve much more than your score :-)

Comment: @Sebastiano:  thanks for the kind words, my friend!

Answer (score 0):

Given

$\frac{dS}{dx}=C(x) \Rightarrow SdS=S(x)C(x)dx \cdots (1)$

$\frac{dC}{dx}=-S(x) \Rightarrow CdC=-S(x)C(x)dx \cdots (2)$

Adding $(1)$ and $(2)$ and integrating, we have

$\int (SdS+CdC)=\int0dx \Rightarrow S^2(x)+C^2(x)=k \cdots (3)$

From the initial conditions of $S(0)$ & $C(0)$, we have $k=1$.

$\therefore$ From equation $(3)$, we have $S^2(x)+C^2(x)=1$.